# Enter / Go key on Android keyboard when focusing a numberfield

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2, enter

my problem is that I can't catch any event on pressing enter key while "inside" a numberfield.

I started by listening to action event, then tried to catch keyup event and check the keycode. None of those are working for me:

```
xtype: 'numberfield',
cls: 'bordered_input',
label: '',
name: 'value',
itemId: 'stavif_value',
listeners: {
    keyup: function(numberfield, e){
        if(e.event.keyCode == 13) 
            console.log('KEYUP CATCHED');
    },
    action: function(){
        console.log('ACTION CATCHED');
    }  
}
```

Then I moved the numberfield inside a form.Panel and tried to catch the beforesubmit event:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    submitOnAction: true, 
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [                  
                {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    cls: 'bordered_input',
                    label: '',
                    name: 'hodnota',
                    itemId: 'stavif_hodnota'
                }                                
            ],
            listeners: {
                beforesubmit: function(form, values, options) {
                    console.log('BEFORESUBMIT inside FIELDSET');
                }
           }
       }
    ],
    listeners: {
        beforesubmit: function(form, values, options) {
            console.log('BEFORESUBMIT inside form.Panel');
        }
     }
});
```

I've put the 'listeners' thingy to fieldset aswell (originally I've had it without the fieldset), just to be sure that I'm not missing anything. However I didn't succeed once again.

What makes me confused is that when I use textfield instead of numberfield I am able to catch the keyup and the action events (dunno about the beforesubmit though, didn't try that).

Comment: I am facing the same problem. The keyup is captured but still the default action executes

Answer (score 0):

There is a special key event listener for `numberfield`. Try

```
listeners: {
                specialkey: function(field, e){
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                        console.log('Enter pressed');
                    }
                }
            }
```